# Windows 11 PC is ignoring domain GPO to allow inbound ICMP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

we have joined a Windows 11 machine for the first time to our domain, however something is not working as expected. For instance, the machine cannot be pinged, although the domain GPO sets a rule in the firewall to allow this.

```
Computer Configuration 
 Policies 
  Administrative Templates  
   Network/Network Connections/Windows Defender Firewall/Domain Profile 
    Allow inbound echo request Enabled
```

The above policy is applied to the offending Windows 11 machine, as shown in rsop.msc, and the server has been updated with Windows 11 October 21 .ADMX files beforehand ...

Windows 11 machine's network profile seems to be correctly set to domain:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-NetConnectionProfile                                                                        

Name             : ourdoamin.blablabla
InterfaceAlias   : WiFi
InterfaceIndex   : 10
NetworkCategory  : DomainAuthenticated
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

Comment: Is the Windows 11 computer using the Domain network profile? The firewall profile is applied to the corresponding network profile.

Comment: Yes, see the updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party preinstalled security suite was the culprit.
Uninstalled and everything working as expected